# reconfigure mysql question

Tags: server, upgrade, 16.04, mysql, database

what happens if i use this command?

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server
```

and more important :  what happenes on my databases? are they droped?

note:
when i upgrade my ubuntu 16.04 in last night , change some settings that i modified , then i can't connect to mysql
when i try to connect db, i see this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

i googled very much! but there isn't clear solution!
i think that command can be help me to solve problem

thanks u for attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had problems with upgrading mysql on upgrade to 16.04. You do not have to worry about losing your data. I uninstalled mysql and installed it again and did many other (foolish) things because mysql upgrade did not work. I believe I messed it because apparmor configuration was not upgraded and then apparmor did not allow mysql to access its configuration files.

Anyway, you can use the command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server
```

with no fear. On upgrade, the databases were converted to a newer format, but I lost no data and all accounts, permissions and passwords for database access were also preserved.